# Regular Expression - Only match Alphanumerics and a SINGLE whitespace between words

Tags: regex

I'm new to Regular Expressions...
I've been asked a regular expression that accepts Alphanumerics, a few characters more, and only ONE whitespace between words.

For example : 
This should match :

```
"Hello world"
```

This shouldn't :

```
"Hello  world"
```

Any ideas?

This was my expression:

```
[\w':''.'')''(''\[''\]''{''}''-''_']+$
```

I already tried the \s? (the space character once or never - right? ) but I didn't get it to work.

Comment: I think the main problem with your regex as written is the quotes around the characters you want to allow. That, rather than a problem with using `\s?` is probably what was tripping you up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Oniguruma regex syntax, you could do something like:

```
^[\w\.:\(\)\[\]{}\-_](?: ?[\w\.:\(\)\[\]{}\-_])*$
```

Assuming that the 'other characters' are . : () [] {} - _

This regex will match a string that must begin and end with a word character or one of the other allowed characters and cannot have more than one space in a row.

If you're using the `x` flag (ignore whitespace in regular expression) you'll need to do this instead:

```
^[\w\.:\(\)\[\]{}\-_](?:\ ?[\w\.:\(\)\[\]{}\-_])*$
```

The only difference is the `\` in front of the space.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solves my problem!
I only changed the " ?" to "\s?" and it worked:

" ^(?:\s?[\w\.:\(\)\[\]{}\-_])+$ "

Comment: I used space instead of `\s` since it didn't sound like you wanted to match tab characters, newlines, and other assorted whitespace. `\s` will match anything that's considered whitespace, while using a space character will only match a space specifically.

Comment: Emily, I think this is because of the programs I was using. I guess they interpret the expressions in a different way...

Comment: Probably it's using the `x` flag which ignores the whitespace in the regex. I've updated the answer for use with an `x` flag as well.

Comment: Yep! That does it! Thanks a lot!
Im sorry I can't rate you, it says I dont have 15 points yet.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
^[\w\.:\(\)\[\]{}\-]+( [\w\.:\(\)\[\]{}\-]+)*$
```

Matches:

- `^[\w\.:\(\)\[\]{}\-]+`: line begins with 1 or more acceptable characters (underscore is included in \w).
- `( [\w\.:\(\)\[\]{}\-]+)`: look to include a single separator character and 1 or more acceptable characters.
- `*$`: repeat single separator and word 0 or more times.

Tested:

- `Hello(space)World`: TRUE
- `Hello(space)(space)World`: FALSE
- `Hello`: TRUE
- `Hello(space)`: FALSE
- `Hello(tab)World`: FALSE

Comment: Joel, can you tell me where are you testing this?: I'm trying both on Expresso and Rad Software Regular Expression designer... different results on each program :S

Comment: http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html which I believe uses a java regex engine.

Comment: This is much more efficient than Emily's regex.